# Apache Beam Pipeline: OutOfMemoryException while writing Avro files to Google Cloud Storage with Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-storage, out-of-memory, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

We have a batch pipeline developed in Apache Beam Java SDK 2.34.0 and running with Google Cloud Dataflow runner. We have a step to write avro files. Avro write is throwing OutofMemory exception. Batch is trying to write around 800 avro files, each file not more than 50kb.

```
Error message from worker: An OutOfMemoryException occurred. Consider specifying higher memory instances in PipelineOptions.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:60)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn.finishBundle(WriteFiles.java:974)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.buildContentChunk(MediaHttpUploader.java:579)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:380)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:308)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:528)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:85)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Configurations:**
WorkerType: n2-standard-4
numShards: 10

Writer configuration:

```
public static Write<String, Evaluation> getAvroWriter(ValueProvider<String> avroFilesPath,
            ValueProvider<Integer> shards) {
        return FileIO.<String, Evaluation>writeDynamic().withNumShards(shards)
                .by(Evaluation::getId).withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .withNaming(Contextful.fn(fileName -> (window, pane, numShards, shardIndex, compression) -> {
                    return fileName + ".avro";
                })).via(AvroIO.sink(Evaluation.class)).to(avroFilesPath);
    }
```

Took heap dump for inspection, Surprised by seeing memory used by stream/byte[]. 
[heap dump dominator tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWhR9.jpg)
[top_consumer_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmcBp.jpg)

Is something wrong in Apache Beam IO Library with dataflow runner?

Comment: Do you need X amount of files per id? What is the number of files produced if you don't set `numShards`?

Comment: @Bruno It’s exactly one file per id, I didn’t check temp files count. But final/complete files count is fixed.